# Regex to match last character of a string

Tags: regex, perl

So I have little problem, I need to check in perl if last character in string is "a". I know, that I can do it in this way:

```
$test = "mama";
$test2 = substr $test, -1
```

And now just check if $test2 not equal "a". But how can I do this with regex?

Comment: it's obvious you never tried to read about pcre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$` matches the end of the string:

```
my $test = "mama";

print "Terminal 'a' in $test\n" if $test =~ /a$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, [`$` does not necessarily match the end of the string](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlreref#ANCHORS):

> ```
> ^  Match string start (or line, if /m is used)
> $  Match string end (or line, if /m is used) or before newline
> \b Match word boundary (between \w and \W)
> \B Match except at word boundary (between \w and \w or \W and \W)
> \A Match string start (regardless of /m)
> \Z Match string end (before optional newline)
> \z Match absolute string end
> \G Match where previous m//g left off
> \K Keep the stuff left of the \K, don't include it in $&
> ```

Therefore, to check if the last character of `$s` really is `'a'`, you *must* use:

```
if ($s =~ /a\z/) { ...
```

because

```
$ perl -E 'say "yes" if "a\n" =~ /a$/'
yes
```